# Grab the Location of LocationClient before it is provided to Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, location-client

I'm messing with the `LocationClient` in combination with `Google Maps V2`, because I wanna integrate it in my app and `outdate the LocationListener, LocationSource combination`.

One `requirement` of the app I'm working on is to `grab the Location` provided from the LocationListener, `modify` that Location `and pass it to Maps` via LocationSource.

This is working but I don't know how to manage this using LocationClient. Because it seems that it automatically provide the Location to Maps and there is no point to grab the Location before where I can modify it.

Do I miss something or is that a fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocationClient` works similarly to the original Android Location API in that it takes in a LocationListener as an argument to listen for location updates:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

The `LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location location)` method then gets called by the platform with new locations.

Therefore, you can use the same strategy for passing location updates to the Maps API v2 via the [`LocationSource`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) and [`LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener) to control what locations get shown on the map.

First, declare an `OnLocationChangedListener` object in your `Activity`:

```
private OnLocationChangedListener mListener; //Used to update the map with new location
```

Then, implement LocationSource for your activity, something like:

`public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity implements LocationSource{`

In `onCreate()`, set up the `LocationSource` for this `Activity` when you're setting up the Map object:

```
...
//Show the location on the map
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//Set location source
mMap.setLocationSource(this);
...
```

Then, add the methods required for the `LocationSource` interface:

```
/**
 * Maps V2 Location updates
 */
@Override
public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;       
}

/**
 * Maps V2 Location updates
 */
@Override
public void deactivate() {
     mListener = null;      
}
```

The final part is passing in the location updates from a normal `LocationListener` to the `Activity` implementing the `LocationSource`:

```
//Update real-time location on map
if(mListener != null){
    mListener.onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Comment: Actually you can replace the LocationManager with the LocationClient almost one by one. I was a lil' confused by the easy use of this...